# adding background colour to webpage

Tags: asp.net-core, colors, background-color

new to ASP.net core, how do I add background colour to the page using the cshtml? I am using the automatically generated page but this is invariable white with black text and it doesn't seem to like the use of  inline.

Comment: Find `wwwroot\css\site.css` file and put your styles there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .net  core application,there is a default layout in  shared/_layout.cshtml.And each view will use the layout.And in _layout.cshtml,we often reference site.css in `<head></head>`.So if you want to change the background color of  all the pages,you can change the style in site.css.Also, you can change the style in _layout.cshtml by.

For example,I change the background color of  body:

In site.css:

```
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

In _layout.cshtml:

```
<style>
    body {
    background-color:red;
    }
</style>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like...

```
<body style="background-color:red">
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31232162)